# Convert Node to String

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing

I have a xml parser which was written by someone I hired, a few months ago. The xml is pulled in from a third party. This party, recently put a new important tag on the xml, called SourceName. I messed with the code a bit, and I got most of it I believe, but I get a weird output.

```
<SourceInfo>
   <SourceName1>NYT</SourceName1>
   <SourceName2>BDN</SourceName2>
</SourceInfo>

NodeList sourceList = element.getElementsByTagName("SourceName1");
    if(sourceList.getLength()>0){
        Element sourceElem=(Element) sourceList.item(0);
        Node sourceName=(Node) sourceElem.getChildNodes().item(0);
        System.out.println(sourceName);
    }
```

the unwanted return is [#text: NYT] rather than a string of NYT.

So, the question is, how do I convert Node sourceName to String sourceName of the value NYT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The node probably has a method to do that. Without knowing what parser you are using nobody here will be able to help you. And I'm certain this is in the API doc of the parser.

Comment: Have you tried getNodeValue() in your System.out.println statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
System.out.println(sourceName.getNodeValue());
```

*** Jochen's comment is valid.  I assumed that you were using the [DOM parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) built in to java.  If not, then this answer is probably wrong.

Comment: Yeah, AMit Bhargava was also correct. Is there any way to shorten the code? In php this can be done in live, why would java require 4lines?

Comment: The DOM technology has been there since jdk1.4 (over 10 years).  It is no longer considered the best, but is kept for compatibility.  JAXB or XSLT would probably better meet your needs.